# In how big percentage of gravity core does play role in?

Tags: experimental-physics, newtonian-gravity

If something would take whole core of earth and done this

$(((coreearth)-(restofearth)):coreearth)*100=X$

What would `X` be?

In short, which part of our planet matters more in gravity, the core, or what's around it? Does the same apply to stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell what your equation means,  but from your words "which part of our planet matters more in gravity, the core, or what's around it", you can define 
$$X=\frac{M_c}{M}=0.29$$
where $M_c$ is the mass of the core and $M$ is the mass of Earth, as obtained from [this link](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1999-11/943288749.Es.r.html).

Since gravity from a spherical body with varying radial density is only dependent on mass, you can effectively say that 29% of Earth's gravity is from the core.

Comment: Your case is homogeneous mass distribution.  It is terribly wrong for the Earth with its huge iron core overlain by rock.

Comment: @UncleAl: No, it's not. It's valid for nonhomogeneous mass distributions too, such as the Earth. All that is required is angular independence of $\rho$.

Answer (score -2):

http://typnet.net/Essays/EarthGrav.htm 
  Here you go, explicitly calculated then graphed
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/EarthGravityPREM.svg

Earth's Mars-sized iron core is an outsized contributor to overall gravity, all the way down to its radius.